# How to calculate the probability of winning the loterry over the course of 1 year

Tags: probability, combinations

So there's this game in Europe where you choose 5 numbers from 1 to 52 plus 2 numbers from 1 to ten! If you play only one time it's pretty easy to calculate the probability! If you play only 1 time you get that you have a 1/(nCr(52,5)*nCr(10,2)) probability of winning! But here's what's messing with me if you play two weeks in a row the winning numbers will change so what's best play the same chosen numbers every week or change them? Hope I'm clear enough! Please feel free to ask for clarifications! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing the numbers or not doesn't change your chances since the events are independent

Comment: what about if I choose 2 different combinations! I'm I more likely to win if I choose both in the same week or in different weeks, or is it the same?

Comment: Well, if there are $P$ different combinations, then the chance they pick one of yours is $2/P$, right? (# favorable cases/ # total cases). On the other hand, if you had only one, it would be $1/P$. Now, since the events in the two weeks are independent, your chance would be $1/P+1/P=2/P$.